# Removing duplicates and sorting (aggs + sort)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find the best solution where a query returns a sorted set, which I then use aggs to remove duplicates, this works fine, however when I add a sort on the query results, e.g.

```
"query": {..},
"sort": {.. "body.make": "asc" ..}
```

I'd like the aggs to also return the results in that order, however it seems to always order on the query score.

```
  // Here I'm collecting all body.vin values to remove duplicates 
  // and then returning only the first in each result set.
  "aggs": {
    "dedup": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 8,
        "field": "body.vin"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dedup_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I've tried to put a term aggregation in between to see if that would sort:

```
// here again same thing, however I attempt to sort on body.make
// in the document, however I now realize that my bucket result
// being each a collection of the duplicates, will sort each duplicate
// and not on the last results.
  "aggs": {
    "dedup": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 8,
        "field": "body.vin"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "order": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "body.make",
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "dedup_docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

But the results from the aggregation are always based on score.

Also I've toyed with the idea or solution of adjusting the scores based on query sort, in this way the aggregation would return the proper order as it returns based on score, but there doesn't seem to be anyway of doing this with the `sort: {}`.

If anyone has had success in sorting results, while removing duplicates, or ideas/suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the most ideal solution since it will only allow the sorting on one field. The best would be to change scores/boosts on sorted results**

Trying to explain it made me realize how this could be done once I grasped the concept of buckets, or more so how they are passed. I would still be interested in the sort + score adjust solution but via aggregates this works:

```
// here we first aggregate all body.make, so first results might
// {"toyota": {body.vin 123}, "toyota": {body.vin 123}...} and the
// next result passed into the dedup aggregate would be say
// {"nissan"...
  "aggs": {
    "sort": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 8,
        "field": "body.make",
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dedup": {
          "terms": {
            "size": 8,
            "field": "body.vin"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "dedup_docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```